# Indefinite integrals and connection with derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives

I know that indefinite integral of $x$ is $\frac{x^2}{2}$ but when u graph both $x$ and $\frac{x^2}{2}$ I see no connection between them are there two different perspectives of seeing derivatives as slopes and functions alone I don't know if I'm correct if I'm wrong please someone correct me I'm in my 12 th class in india

Comment: the slope of the line tangent to $y=\dfrac{x^2}2$ at $x$ is $x$

Comment: And the area under the graph of $y=x$ from $x=0$ to $x=a$ is $a^2/2$.